# How to load Hadoop Pig temporary output from job that stopped due to network drop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, temp

I had a Pig job running, but forgot to screen the command, and when the bulk of the job finished (4 hours of mapping), the reduce phase never started, probably because Pig was no longer running.  I have the output from the mapper in pig_tmp, but I cannot figure out how to reload it with Piglatin.

The map portion (I assume) was me using `STREAMING`, and the output was (chararray, float, float).

According to [Pig Docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#binstorage), Pig uses `BinStorage()` "to load and store the temporary data that is generated between multiple MapReduce jobs."  Based on this, I tried the following with no luck:

```
A = LOAD '.pig_tmp/tmp-238234234/tmp23423423/part-m-00000' 
    USING BinStorage() AS (col1:chararray, col2:float, col3:float);
DUMP A;
-- "Inputs(s): Successfully read 0 records (5402065 bytes) from "..."
```

no luck, so try no types on columns:

```
A = LOAD '.pig_tmp/tmp-238234234/tmp23423423/part-m-00000' 
    USING BinStorage() AS (col1, col2, col3);
DUMP A;
-- "Inputs(s): Successfully read 0 records (5402065 bytes) from "..."
```

still no luck, so trying no columns

```
A = LOAD '.pig_tmp/tmp-238234234/tmp23423423/part-m-00000' 
    USING BinStorage();
DUMP A;
-- "Inputs(s): Successfully read 0 records (5402065 bytes) from "..."
```

I repeated this with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 columns in the "AS (...)" block, thinking maybe Pig was adding some extra columns in there. No luck as well.

If I view the output of the file, it is clearly binary data (and is 5mb large as mentioned above).

Comment: This sounds hard :\ I'd be surprised if this was possible.

Comment: You're probably right.  Restarting the job isn't too bad, so I went that route, but figured get this out here in case someone else has the same problem but with a really big job. :)